# Regex to find occurence at random position

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a regular expression to find two HTML attributes (`title` and `style`) in a string and get that value. In some cases the `style` attribute doesn't exists, so then i only need the `title` value.

So far i have it working for situations where the `title` attribute precedes the `style` attribute, no matter if the `style` is defined or not.

The problem occurs when, for some reason, the `style` attribute is defined *before* the `title` attribute.

I'm using this regular expression in Drupal, so i don't worry too much about inconsistent HTML, but the attribute order seems a problem.

Here's the expression i have so far

```
/<img\s{1}.*title=\"(.*)\"\s{1}.*(style=\"(.*)\"\s{1}.*)?>/siU
```

I've searched through articles on the internet but can't find a working solution. I hope someone can help me out. I'm puzzling on it for longer then i'm supposed to allready.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which value(s) would you like to get? `title`, `style` or both?

Comment: I always suggest people to split the task into multiple regular expressions. So the easiest solution is to get the full IMG-Tag with the first regular expression and pass that tag to 2 new regular expressions as the input. One for finding the title attribute and one for finding the style attribute.

Comment: I need to have the title attribute and if available the style as well. Perhaps creating two regular expressions might work. Will try that

Comment: Yep, @Scordo Splitting it in half did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A regex is not the best tool for this task. Use a DOM parser instead. Here's one solution using PHP's built-in DOMDocument class:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<img style="width:20px" title="Some Title" src="foobar.jpg" />
<img title="Some Title" src="foobar.jpg" />
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img)
{
    if (!$img->hasAttribute('style') && $img->hasAttribute('title'))
    {
        echo $img->getAttribute('title') . "\n";
    }
    elseif ($img->hasAttribute('style') && $img->hasAttribute('title'))
    {
        echo $img->getAttribute('style') . "\n";
        echo $img->getAttribute('title') . "\n\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
width:20px
Some Title

Some Title
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/141872)

Comment: What? No snarky remark as to how reg-ex cannot be used to parse (X)HTML? +1 for the obviously correct solution.

Comment: I know, even that you're right, but i need to have it in a module that only allows me to use a regular expression. And unfortunately i'm not in the position (and not have the capabilities) to write a custom module

Comment: @Maurice: I've no idea what you mean by a "module", but if you're using PHP, then you'll be able to use DOMDocument class. It ships with PHP 5+. Why can't you use it? If you must absolutely use a regex, then split this into two expressions. That way, it'll be a lot more easier.